# Resolve Keywords to its values at runtime of Cucumber steps

Tags: java, cucumber-jvm

When I enter the name foo_SCENARIO_UUID in serach text field

Implementation:

```
@When("^I enter the name "([^"]*)" in serach text field$")
public void i_enter_someText_in_search_textField(String searckKey) throws Throwable {
    pageCollection.searchPage().enterKeyword(searchKey);
}
```

My question is how to set wherever I use 'SCENARIO_UUID' in my Features to the value of System.currentTimeMillis().

Is there anyway I can override Cucumberoptions resolving to these values instead of writing logic in each step implementation.

**We have this option in Jbehave as**

```
@Override
public Configuration configuration() {
    if (config != null)
        return config;

    config = useParameterConverters(new ParameterConverters()
                                   .addConverters(new StringConverter()));
```

I couldnt find any such option in Cucumber to make sure it search for a new string everytime we run the test :(

Answer (score 0):

```
public static class Scenario_Uuid_transform extends Transformer<String> {

    @Override
    public String transform(String aString) {
        if (aString.endsWith("_SCENARIO_UUID")) {
            return Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis());
            // Or if you wanted foo_ prepended
            // return aString.replaceFirst("SCENARIO_UUID", Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        else {
            return aString;
        }
    }
}


@When("^I enter the name "([^"]*)" in serach text field$")
public void i_enter_someText_in_search_textField(@Transform(Scenario_Uuid_transform.class) String searckKey) throws Throwable {
    pageCollection.searchPage().enterKeyword(searchKey);
}
```

See [Class Transformer](https://cucumber.github.io/api/cucumber/jvm/javadoc/cucumber/api/Transformer.html) for an explanation.

Comment: @"vicky dev" I used to do transforms with ruby cucumber all the time. cucumber-jvm finally did support this. It was a good question.